# Question about be going to or will

Tags: grammar, questions, future-tense, will-vs-going-to

Fill in the blanks:

> The phone is ringing, ...
>
> 1.I'll pick it up
>
> 2.I'm going to pick it up

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Both options are grammatical and idiomatic, so unless you use the [edit] link to provide more detail than this, your question will unfortunately be closed. Please read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Here is a [**link**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Often the two expressions get used interchangeably, a lot depends on how it's said and surrounding context.

However, without anything else, in your example with a ringing telephone

> I *will* pick it up.
>   *I'll get it*  *[more idiomatic]*

would mean you will answer the phone **now** and  has more **immediacy and determination** than

> I *am going* to pick it up.

which might mean you are about *to start* to go pick up the phone.